# URL that will reload the current page

Tags: android, ios, http, web, reload

Got a bit of a strange problem. I've got a URL field that I'm sending to Android and iOS app clients. In certain situations, I need to replace the value of that field with a URL that will either perform a no-op or reload the app's current page when it tries to load it. Is that even possible with just a URL?

I've already had them try `.` to no avail. That will pop up a toast saying that the feature needs a web browser.